# How do I mock a bloc in Flutter, with states being emitted in response to events from a widget under test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to test a widget that makes use of a bloc.  I'd like to be able to emit states from my mocked bloc in response to events being fired by the widget under test.  I've tried a number of approaches without success.  I'm not sure if I'm making some simple error or if I'm approaching the problem all wrong.

Here is a simplified project which demonstrates my issue.  (the complete code for this can be found at https://github.com/andrewdixon1000/flutter_bloc_mocking_issue.git)

**very simple bloc**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  MyBloc() : super(FirstState());

  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(
    MyEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is TriggerStateChange) {
      yield SecondState();
    }
  }
}

@immutable
abstract class MyEvent {}

class TriggerStateChange extends MyEvent {}


@immutable
abstract class MyState {}

class FirstState extends MyState {}

class SecondState extends MyState {}
```

**My widget under test**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'bloc/my_bloc.dart';
import 'injection_container.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirsPageState createState() => _FirsPageState();
}

class _FirsPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => serviceLocator<MyBloc>(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 1")),
        body: Container(
          child: BlocConsumer<MyBloc, MyState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is SecondState) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "SECONDPAGE");
              }
            },
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is FirstState) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("State is FirstState"),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context).add(TriggerStateChange());
                        },
                        child: Text("Change state")),
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return Text("some other state");
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**my widget test**
This is where I'm struggling.  What I'm doing is loading the widget and then tapping the button.  This causes the widget to add an event to the bloc.  What I want to be able to do is have my mock bloc emit a state in response to this, such that the widget's BlocConsumer's listener will see the state change the navigate.  As you can see from the comment in the code I've tried a few things without luck.  Current nothing I've tried results in the listener seeing a state change.

```
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart' as mocktail;
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:test_bloc_issue/bloc/my_bloc.dart';
import 'package:test_bloc_issue/first_page.dart';

class MockMyBloc extends MockBloc<MyEvent, MyState> implements MyBloc {}
class FakeMyState extends Fake implements MyState {}
class FakeMyEvent extends Fake implements MyEvent {}

void main() {
  MockMyBloc mockMyBloc;
  mocktail.registerFallbackValue<MyState>(FakeMyState());
  mocktail.registerFallbackValue<MyEvent>(FakeMyEvent());
  mockMyBloc = MockMyBloc();

  var nextScreenPlaceHolder = Container();

  setUpAll(() async {
    final di = GetIt.instance;
    di.registerFactory<MyBloc>(() => mockMyBloc);
  });

  _loadScreen(WidgetTester tester) async {
    mocktail.when(() => mockMyBloc.state).thenReturn(FirstState());
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: FirstPage(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          'SECONDPAGE': (context) => nextScreenPlaceHolder
        }
      )
    );
  }

  testWidgets('test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await _loadScreen(tester);
    await tester.tap(find.byType(ElevatedButton));
    await tester.pump();
    
    // What do I need to do here to mock the state change that would
    // happen in the real bloc when a TriggerStateChange event is received,
    // such that the listener in my BlocConsumer will see it?
    // if tried:
    // whenListen(mockMyBloc, Stream<MyState>.fromIterable([SecondState()]));
    // and
    // mocktail.when(() => mockMyBloc.state).thenReturn(SecondState());
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byWidget(nextScreenPlaceHolder), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look and [opened a pull request](https://github.com/andrewdixon1000/flutter_bloc_mocking_issue/pull/1) with my suggestions. I highly recommend thinking of your tests in terms of notifications and reactions. In this case, I recommend having one test to verify that when the button is tapped, the correct event is added to the bloc (the bloc is notified). Then I recommend having a separate test to ensure that when the state changes from FirstState to SecondState that the correct page is rendered (the UI reacts to state changes appropriately). In the future, I highly recommend taking a look at the [example apps](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples) since most of them are fully tested.